# Hide Empty Zero Data Points in SSRS Line Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have an SSRS line chart that I need to figure out how to hide empty data points - stop the line from making markers/continuing the line where Category Group values are zero:

[image]

The values and series and groups are setup as so:

[image]

With the data looking like this:

[image]

I have tried filtering both at the chart level and the Category Group levels to filter out data that would create groups for Series 2020 and Category October/November/December, this creating or filling those points in my mind:

[image]

Where the expression is "=DateSerial(YEAR(today()),MONTH(today()), 1)" achieving the net result of filtering out data points/rows that from an incomplete month - meaning when the report would be run on 10/10/2020, only data from before 10/1/2020 should be used to generate groups.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `COUNT()` which will always return a value, zero if there are no records to count.

I created a simple dataset and using count of FILE_NUMBER I got this (replicating your issue) ...

[image]

The easiest way round this is to change the value expression to something like this...

[image]

[image]

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!FILE_NUMBER.Value = Nothing, 0, 1))
```

This way we add 1 to the sum for every non-empty value and nothing if it's empty. If the total sum is still empty, by default, the chart will not plot that point.

So we end up with this...

[image]